# Is there any shortcuts for creating kotlin class?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, android-studio-3.0

I sometimes create a lot of classes and a keyboard shortcut will save my time. Thank you in advance. Do I have to right-click on the package name each time ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts for creating new class in kotlin is

> Command+N - then select the kotlin file or class

Comment: thx ! on windows i can do this : `CTRL + MAJ + A -  then select the kotlin file or class`

Comment: @diAz what is MAJ ? tnx

Comment: @Fortran it's SHIFT sorry

Answer (score 0):

Do "CTRL + SHIFT + A" key combination then type "Create Kotlin" and select file or class or whatever